# Python Webscraping Clicking Via Coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, pyautogui

When I tried to web scrape a site I was forced to use pyautogui to move the mouse around in order to accept terms. In the process I enter the coordinates I want the mouse to click. But my question is will the coordinates be affected if I run it on another machine, like ubuntu? Is there a way to make the coordinates a global value so it won't be affected?

Comment: Yes it (most probably) will, what you probably want to do is using a template to match the object. Take a look at the `locateOnScreen` method. It is also explainedin the [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) for a calculator.

Comment: Alright, appreciate the help!